# Install ree-1.8.7 with RVM on Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, xcode, rvm, osx-mountain-lion

I had a fresh install of Mountain Lion and installed the **Xcode Command Line Tools**, .  I was able to get **homebrew** running and installed **RVM**.  Unfortunately, I can't get RVM to install **ree-1.8.7-head**.  It fails when compiling.  I thought it was related to X11, so I installed **XQuartz**.  Still no joy.  Then I went ahead and installed the full **Xcode from the app store**.  Still no joy.  Anyone gotten this going on a fresh Mountain Lion install?

From the bottom of the **.rvm/log/ree-1.8.7-head/make.log**:

```
Find Tcl/Tk libraries. Make tcltklib.so which is required by Ruby/Tk.
gcc -I. -I../.. -I../../. -I../.././ext/tk -DHAVE_RB_SAFE_LEVEL -DHAVE_RB_HASH_LOOKUP -DHAVE_RB_PROC_NEW -DHAVE_RB_OBJ_TAINT -DHAVE_ST_PTR -DHAVE_ST_LEN -DRUBY_VERSION=\"1.8.7\" -DRUBY_RELEASE_DATE=\"2012-02-08\"  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -DWITH_TCL_ENABLE_THREAD=0 -fno-common -g -O2 -pipe -fno-common   -c stubs.c
In file included from stubs.c:10:
/usr/include/tk.h:78:23: error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
In file included from stubs.c:10:
/usr/include/tk.h:549: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘Window’
/usr/include/tk.h:549: error: ‘Window’ declared as function returning a function
```

.
.

```
/usr/include/tkDecls.h:1240: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute

__’ before ‘Tk_GetBitmapFromObj’
/usr/include/tkDecls.h:1245: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/tkDecls.h:1356: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/tkDecls.h:1362: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/tkDecls.h:1387: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘GC’
/usr/include/tkDecls.h:1399: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘GC’
/usr/include/tkDecls.h:1413: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘Pixmap’
/usr/include/tkDecls.h:1420: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘XColor’
/usr/include/tkDecls.h:1448: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘Pixmap’
/usr/include/tkDecls.h:1524: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/tkDecls.h:1621: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘Drawable’
/usr/include/tkDecls.h:1656: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/tkDecls.h:1661: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/tkDecls.h:1692: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘XColor’
make[1]: *** [stubs.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 16):

try

```
rvm reinstall 1.8.7 --without-tcl --without-tk
```

but still your problem might to be related to gcc-4.2 -> it's required for MRI ruby, there are some successes with llvm/clang, but still it fails with `Fibers`

Comment: Is there a better way to set up Mountain Lion?  I'm thinking of starting over fresh tomorrow.

Comment: The --disable-tcl --disable-tk options still failed, but I added more from the make log to see if that gives any clues.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me for REE as well (I have a legacy project still using it).

Comment: This solved the error in /usr/include/tkDecls.h:1692. I have XCode 4.6 installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need tcl or tk and are using rbenv, this should work:

```
brew install https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/master/apple-gcc42.rb

CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 CONFIGURE_OPTS="--without-tcl --without-tk" rbenv install 1.8.7-p358
```