# Why doesn't OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion find X11 libraries when building software?

Tags: x11, osx-mountain-lion, dyld

So, we all know that Mountain Lion doesn't ship with X11 anymore and users needing X11 are directed to download Xquartz. Xquartz installs to `/opt`, but it also symlinks `X11` and `X11R6` to `/usr`. But when building software that requires linking to X11 include files, I've discovered that I must pass an environment variable adding `/usr/X11/include` (or `/opt/X11/include`) to the library search path to get `./configure` to find the X11 libraries. My question is *why?*

I've done some research on Google (many results pointing back to Stack Overflow), and I've read Apple's documentation, and these sources all indicate that there is no equivalent in OS X to the `/etc/ld.so.conf` file found in many (if not all) Linux distributions. Apple even states that `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is empty by default. However, under Lion (with Apple's last 'official' X11 installed), the same `./configure` scripts would find the X11 libraries without adding anything to the library search path.

So, *why* can't `./configure` scripts find X11 libraries in Mountain Lion without explicit modification of the library search path?

Comment: What's an example of an X11 app you are trying to configure ... and the output of configure?  If I download [xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/), for example, it is finding my X libs on Mountain Lion and I don't think I've done anything special (aside from installing XQuartz).

Comment: Specifically, Ruby 1.8.7. You can see the issue and solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664835/mountain-lion-rvm-install-1-8-7-x11-error

As I said in the original question, I have "fixed" the problem. I just was wondering if anyone knows why this behavior is different in Mountain Lion with Xquartz as opposed to Lion with Apple X11.

Answer (score 1):

Asked more than a year ago... but as I came here with a similar problem...

Note that in the mentioned ruby question, there was no *library search path* being modified.
That solution just set an environment variable that is picked up by many Makefiles as the flags for the C++ compiler. That example defined the build time -I *ncludepath*, i.e. where to search for .h *eaders* -- not *libraries* (which would have been a -L option to your compiler/linker). Both would have been *build time* options.
Whether LD_LIBRARY_PATH or DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH -- both are environment variables that are considered by the dynamic linker at *runtime*. (For more, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker )

I have no pre-10.8 machine at hand, but guess that there might have been a symlink
/usr/include/X11 -> /opt/X11/include/X11 -- otherwise I have no Idea atm how
it could have worked before, assuming same sources...

This is another potential solution for such problems (just fixed my realvnc build):

```
$ autoconf
$ ./configure
```

So your question for "why?" could be eventually answered with: Because your sources contained a 'pre-built' configure script that was based on older autotools that did not include
/opt/X11/include as a potential location to search for X11 includes or simply did not get some of the above mentioned compile time flags right on your current system.
I have autoconf installed through homebrew -- ahh, great stuff, cheers.