# rvm can no longer install 1.8.7-p352 on Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mountain-lion

I upgraded rvm to 1.15.8, then went back down to 1.15.7 after having some problems in zsh. After downgrading, my Ruby 1.9+ versions went back in fine, but 1.8.7 won't install again.

There are two errors that are occurring:

```
Error running 'patch -F 25 -p1 -N -f <"/Users/me/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.8.7/stdout-rouge-fix.patch"', please read /Users/me/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p352/patch.apply.stdout-rouge-fix.log
```

The contents of that file are:

```
[2012-09-11 01:05:59] patch -F 25 -p1 -N -f <"/Users/me/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.8.7/stdout-rouge-fix.patch"
patching file lib/mkmf.rb
Hunk #1 FAILED at 201.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file lib/mkmf.rb.rej
```

and:

```
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/me/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p352/make.log
```

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

and the contents of that file are (only the first few lines beginning with the errors):

```
Fail to find [tclConfig.sh, tkConfig.sh]
Use MacOS X Frameworks.

Find Tcl/Tk libraries. Make tcltklib.so which is required by Ruby/Tk.
gcc-4.2 -I. -I../.. -I../../. -I../.././ext/tk -DHAVE_RB_SAFE_LEVEL -DHAVE_RB_HASH_LOOKUP -DHAVE_RB_PROC_NEW -DHAVE_RB_OBJ_TAINT -DHAVE_ST_PTR -DHAVE_ST_LEN -DRUBY_VERSION=\"1.8.7\" -DRUBY_RELEASE_DATE=\"2011-06-30\"  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -DWITH_TCL_ENABLE_THREAD=0 -fno-common -g -O2  -fno-common -pipe -fno-common   -c stubs.c
In file included from stubs.c:10:
/usr/include/tk.h:78:23: error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
In file included from stubs.c:10:
/usr/include/tk.h:549: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘Window’
/usr/include/tk.h:549: error: ‘Window’ declared as function returning a function
/usr/include/tk.h:552: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘XEvent’
/usr/include/tk.h:561: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘Tk_ClassCreateProc’
/usr/include/tk.h:655: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘Bool’
/usr/include/tk.h:677: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘Bool’
/usr/include/tk.h:756: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘Display’
/usr/include/tk.h:902: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘XPoint’
/usr/include/tk.h:996: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘Display’
```

One of the applications I support is 1.8.7. I am dead in the water. This looks like it might be a problem with Mountain Lion vs. rvm. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

UPDATE:

I got over the first error by doing "reinstall" instead of just "install". Even though 1.8.7-p352 was not in the list of rubies given by the command "rvm list rubies".

Comment: You should maybe post this on http://serverfault.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Comment: @Double I answer most of the RVM questions - and most of them are posted here - posting them elsewhere will most likely longer the time to get answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

it is problem in detecting tcl/tk by ruby 1.8.7, the solution is to disable it:

```
rvm reinstall 1.8.7 --without-tcl --without-tk
```

the other solution when tcl/tk is needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11666019/497756

Comment: What is tcl/tk? How do I know wether i will need them? Edit: Do I only need tcl and tk when I want to build a ruby GUI? (http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_tk_tutorial.html)

Comment: if you did not know what they are then you do not need it, it's really old way and it's rarely used as the interfaces are very ugly

Comment: It seems like a very bad idea to include these by default.

Answer (score 6):

I think I ended up with two similar questions on sf here. My main problem was that the tcl.h include file on Mountain Lion (location: /usr/include/tcl.h symlinked) could not resolve an internal reference it had to "X11/Xlib.h". I thought that installing tcl and tk through homebrew would fix the problem by generating a path to Xlib.h that could be resolved. So I ran:

```
brew install tcl
```

and:

```
brew install tk
```

and:

```
rvm remove 1.8.7-p352
rvm install 1.8.7-p352
```

and it worked. But Michal's answer above would have worked just as well I think. This answer will serve to help people build it that need tcl and tk.

Comment: Homebrew no longer seems to have tcl and tk.