# Mountain Lion install rvm ree-1.8.7

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mountain-lion

I tried following this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664835/mountain-lion-rvm-install-1-8-7-x11-error/11666019#11666019), but I get the following problems:

```
$ export CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/X11/include
$ CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm reinstall ree-1.8.7
/Users/username/.rvm/src/ree-1.8.7-2012.02 has already been removed.
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02 has already been removed.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10/x86_64/ree-1.8.7-2012.02.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
You requested building with '/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2' but it is not in your path.
```

Is there something else I am doing wrong? I am using the October release of Command Line Tools from Apple, if that helps...

Comment: Did you look to see if `/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2` is actually there?

Comment: Did you run read `rvm mount` as told by the error?

Comment: Here is what I see when I run 'rvm mount': "The given paths '' either do not point to a ruby installation or are already mounted."

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some discussion on the other answer I got it to work like this...

First, install brew then do this:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install apple-gcc42
```

Then the rest of the solution will work:

```
export CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/X11/include
CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm reinstall ree-1.8.7
```